# Building Project in Azure devops(CI) doesnt build all projects

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, cicd

Building Projects in Azure DevOps (CI) doesn't build all projects.

I tried to build the Solution but all projects are not build.

Path to project(s) in CI pipelines: **/*.csproj

am not getting any errors message but all projects are not published.

[image: CI pipelines Output]
[image: CI pipelines path details]

[image: Publish Task screenshot]
[image: Build Tas Screenshot]
[image: Publish Artifact Task screenshot]

Comment: What does your log output look like for the publish-step? Btw. you can speed up things a bit, if you add `--no-restore` to the arguments of your build- and publish-step as you are doing an explicit `dotnet restore` beforehand. Same applies to `--no-build` argument in the publish-step since you are also doing an explicit `dotnet build`.

Comment: can you pls share the screenshot for these

Answer (score 0):

Is it a build or publish issue ?

In the logs of the build step, are all projects build ?

In the publish step, did you select "Publish web projects" ?

[image]

If you want to publish other projects (in other artifacts), you may need to add other publish steps.

Comment: Yes, I have given above steps properly, I have updated screenshots in questions

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the publish build artifact step and you see any warning like this:

```
##[warning]Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.
```

You are publishing the default directory: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` while your project is not in this directory. You can check it in your publish build artifact task.

[image]

If it is the case, you need to add a copy file task to copy the artifact files from the build output path to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have given same steps

Comment: Hi @devendar, do the projects that are not published have either a web.config file or wwwroot folder in the directory? You can try unchecking the "Publish web projects" in your dotnet publish task and then please specify the "path to projects" as `**/*.csproj`. Hope it can help.

Comment: Hi @devendar, have you checked the suggestion in my last comment? Does it work on your side? :)